# Can a non domain server obtain it's updates from a domain WSUS

Tags: hyper-v, wsus

Anyone know if it is possible to get a non-domain Server to pick-up it's updates from a domain included WSUS server?

Just thinking about Hyper-V host Servers, in a single server environment clearly this cannot be part of the domain because at the time the VM Host boots the Domain Controllers is not available.  However is there any way to make this Hyper-V Host collect it's updates from the WSUS server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just thinking about Hyper-V host Servers, in a single server environment clearly this cannot 
>   be part of the domain because at the time the VM Host boots the Domain
>   Controllers is not available.

Bas problem here: there is nothing stopping a Hyper-V host that is part of a domain from starting when the DC is not available. I had that for years.

You can not use cluster service - but a regular host can be part of a domain and start all vm's without the dc being available.

THAT SAID: I these days keep 2 machiens around that are both, DC and Hyper-V hosts ;)

And to answer the question - yes. It is posssible. Configuration is via local policy editor. Standard WSUS setup has no authentication mechanisms, i.e. it answers to every computer asking.

Comment: Hi TomTom, decided to give that a try, 2012 Hyper-v Host as a member of the domain with domain controller running as a virtual machine.  First problem I encounter is that Netlogon service fails at boot with eventid: 5719, "Computer was not able to setup a session with a domain controller".

Comment: Found WSUS settings in local policy editor, slightly preferred solution to editing the registry but either works.

Comment: It seems that I can make the Hyper-V host part of the domain.  After a couple of reboots and ignoring that eventid: 5719 + a couple of others, all seems to work fine.  Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's entirely possible, you just need to modify the registry entries outlined [in this technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708449(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Perfect... Just copied those reg hives from an in-domain Server to the external one and it seems to work.  That external server doesn't appear in the WSUS computers list but maybe that is asking for too much.  Many thanks MDMarra.

Comment: Follow-up: That external Server has now even appeared in the WSUS Computers list, just took a little while.